# logic for subtracting and getting variance in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

how to write a logic for getting the below output

```
with b2 as
(
select COUNT(SaLE) As cnt, 
TO_CHAR(date,'YYYY-MON') As Period

  from Order
  where date between date '2020-02-01' and date '2020-02-28'
group by TO_CHAR(BATCH_DTE_CYMD,'YYYY-MON') 

union all
select  COUNT(Sale) As cnt,
TO_CHAR(Date,'YYYY-MON') As Period

  from Order
  where date between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-01-31'
group by TO_CHAR(Date,'YYYY-MON') 

)
select  cnt, Period,
       100*(cnt-lag(cnt,1,cnt) over (order by period))
       /lag(cnt,1,cnt) over (order by period)
       as "variance(%)"
  from b2
 order by period
```

i am getting this ouput

```
Cnt   | period     |    variance(%)
11917 | 2020-FEB   |    0
11707 | 2020-JAN   |    -1.76218847025258034740286984979441134514
```

but i want the this output

```
Cnt   | period     |    variance(%)                                               | sign                                                                                
11917 | 2020-FEB   |    JAN-FEB (Variance we get in feb in % (with no decimal))   | Increase/decrease 
11707 | 2020-JAN   |    0                                                         |  0
```

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the question tags and include data for the table in your query, along with the results you would expect that data to produce. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is, You are using `LAG` on the `CHAR` column(`PERIOD`) which is not correct as **2020-FEB is lower than the 2020-JAN** when the comparison is in the string.

You must use them as the `date` in `LAG` function as following:

```
WITH B2 AS (
    SELECT COUNT(SALE) AS CNT,
           TRUNC(DATE, 'MON') AS PERIOD
      FROM ORDER
     WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-01-01' AND DATE '2020-02-28'
    GROUP BY TRUNC(DATE, 'MON')
)
SELECT
    CNT,
    TO_CHAR(PERIOD,'YYYY-MON') AS PERIOD,
    100 * ( CNT - LAG(CNT, 1, CNT) OVER( ORDER BY PERIOD ) ) 
    / LAG(CNT, 1, CNT) OVER(ORDER BY PERIOD) 
    AS "variance(%)"
FROM B2
ORDER BY PERIOD
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
select cnt,period,
case when variance<>0 then 
'JAN-FEB(Variance we get in feb in '||to_char(round(variance,0))||')' 
else to_char(variance) end as variance,
case when SIGN (variance)<0 then 'Decrease' 
when sign(variance)=0 then 'No Change' else 'Increase' 
end as sign  from(select  cnt, Period,
       100*(cnt-lag(cnt,1,cnt) over (order by period desc ))
       /lag(cnt,1,cnt) over (order by period desc)
       as variance
  from test
)t
order by period
```

I have used `round` function which will convert `-1.7..` to `-2`. you can also use `Ceil`